# So I gotta make a grep or sed?

Tags: bash, shell

Just got a question about `grep`. I have a text file with a lot of entries and I only want a certain number printed out. This is my text and I want the `700` printed out...

```
Dato: 22-02-2018
Mødt ind: 700
Gået hjem: 1600
Overtid:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the file has a simple structure with easily distinguishable records, and you want the value in one of these, it may be easiest to use `awk`:

```
awk '/^Mødt ind:/ { print $NF }' file
```

The `/^Mødt ind:/` means that the following block will trigger for each line that starts with the text `Mødt ind:`.  The block prints `$NF`, which is the value of the last field on the line (`NF` is the field number of the last field, and putting `$` in front of it gives you the value of that field).

---

With standard `sed`:

```
sed -n 's/^Mødt ind: \(.*\)/\1/p' file
```

This does the same matching of the line as `awk`, but replaces the contents of the line with whatever comes after the colon and space.  Normal output is disabled with `-n` and only lines that are modified by the expression are outputted.

I would still go for the `awk` solution as it's more readable and easier to understand/modify.

Comment: Thank you! yours is much better I did it with a grep
grep 'Mødt ind:' Arbejdstid.txt | awk {'print $3'}

Comment: If there a way to make it so that I execute a find command to find the file first? and then do the awk :)

Comment: @peter You have already accepted my answer, and finding the file was not part of the question.  You should either ask a new question, or (but ideally not) un-accept my answer and update the question with the new requirements (this will make people who has already answered grumpy).

Comment: okay, im sorry kinda new to this, I'll do that next time :)

Answer (score 0):

`sed` alone can handle this, as you have already guessed:

```
sed 's/.*ind:\ \(.*\)/\1/;tx;d;:x'
```

It's a search-and-replace operation:

`.*ind:\ \(.*\)` searches for lines starting with any character, followed by `ind:` (the space is escaped). The `\(.*\)` is used for "matching" the rest of the line and stored in the first match, by which the whole line is replaced by: `\1`. The `;tx;d;:x` works like this: `tx` branches to label x if the substitution was successful, `d` deletes line, `:x` is a marker for the label x.

Comment: Without the label and branch: `s/.*ind: \(.*\)/\1/p` (run with `sed -n`). The space needs no escaping.